# problem with implict casting in c and c++

Tags: c++, vector, visual-c++, implicit-conversion

I was doing something as below:

```
int num_of_pairs(std::vector<char>& str)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < str.size() - 1; i++)
    {
      if(str[i] == str[i + 1])
         # Do something
    }
}
```

but when I pass a empty vector of length 0 then still the for loop executes and throws an index error.
vector.size() returns a size_t which unsigned int64 on my compiler and I think compiler is calculating arr.size() - 1  as size_t and then casting to int to check the condition, because when arr.size() is 0 then arr.size() - 1 becomes a very large number probably 2^64 - 1 .

the same thing happens when I do

```
int n = 50000;
unsigned int a = n*(n + 1);
```

It gives me garbage because 50000*50000 becomes 2.5 billon which is overflow for signed integers but unsigned integers can store it.

I have two questions,

1. does I am thinking correct (which I think I am, but want to confirm because I am not netwon or einstien)
2. what is the way to avoid this

Comment: To get terminology straight: there are explicit and implicit _conversions_. A cast is always an explicit conversion done by the programmer. But there are many different kinds of implicit conversions done by the compiler. Thus there is no such thing as an "implicit cast".

Comment: If given example, [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) might be used (so just use iterator instead of index).

Answer (score 2):

The type `std::vector<char>::size_type` that the member function `size` has is an unsigned integer type. So this expression

```
str.size() - 1
```

produces the maximum value of the unsigned integer type provided that `str.size()` is equal to `0` due to the usual arithmetic conversions.

In this condition

```
i < str.size() - 1
```

there is no casting to the type `int`. The left operand again is implicitly converted to the type `std::vector<char>::size_type` due to the same usual arithmetic conversions.

So before the for loop you should check whether `str.size()` is equal to `0`..

Or you could rewrite the loop for example like

```
for( std::decay_t<decltype( str )>::size_type i = 1; i < str.size(); i++)
{
    if(str[i] == str[i - 1])
       # Do something
}
```

As for this code snippet

```
int n = 50000;
unsigned int a = n*(n + 1);
```

then in the expression `n*(n + 1)` there is occurred an overflow for the type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

(1) You are almost right. When arr.size() is 0 then arr.size() - 1 becomes a very large number 2^64 - 1 if size_t is 64-bit number, but then the variable i casting to std::vector::size_type (usually size_t) to check the condition.

Another thing happens here:

```
int n = 50000;
unsigned int a = n*(n + 1);
```

Here, if the `int` is 32-bit, then the `n*(n + 1)` expression execution leads to overflow; there is not casting to unsigned int. The casting to unsigned int applies to result of the `n*(n + 1)` expression, that is unspecified by standard, but should  be defined in the compiler documentation.

(2) There are many ways to rewrite this function:

```
 for(size_t i = 1; i < str.size(); i++)
 {
   if ( str[i - 1] == str[i] )
      // Do something
 }
```

Or

```
int num_of_pairs(std::vector<char>& str)
{
  if ( str.size() < 2 )
    return 0;

  for(size_t i = 0; i < str.size() - 1; i++)
  {
    if(str[i] == str[i + 1])
       # Do something
  }
}
```